# select every 4 rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a way I could select 4 rows in a table and make its background red and select the next 4 rows and make its background blue? its kinda like odd and even but in a different way where a group of rows is selected. Any ideas, help, suggestions, clues, recommendation please?

```
<table>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- even -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would like to suggest you to learn about css nth-child to do this like:  class:nth-child(n%8>=4) { background: red } and class:nth-child(n%8<4) {background: blue}, if you like to use only two color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure css solution, you can do something like this:

```css
table tr:nth-of-type(n) {

  background: blue;

}

table tr:nth-of-type(8n),

table tr:nth-of-type(8n-1),

table tr:nth-of-type(8n-2),

table tr:nth-of-type(8n-3) {

  background: red;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- even -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool but the problem is, the row quantity is dynamic like table has 80 rows or 112 rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful about using the `background` shorthand and supplying only one value. Any [values not supplied will be set to initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) which may not be what is desired. If you're only setting `color` it's safer to use `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use JS for collecting all of tr-elements and set background color of each row as you like:

```js
var trList = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var n = 0;
var color = 'pink';
for(var key in trList) {
 var trElem = trList[key];
 if( n > 3 ) {
   n = 0;
    color == 'pink' ? color = 'lightblue' : color = 'pink';
  }
  trElem.style.backgroundColor = color;
 n++;
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<table>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- even -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- even -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <!--- odd -->
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME</td><td>AGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cvpubto

Comment: what does this "color == 'pink' ? color = 'lightblue' : color = 'pink';" mean?

Comment: this is expression for defining current color of table's row between 2 colors: pink and lightblue. of corse, you can change it as you want